# SQL: Access database once and get the number of data AND the data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcommand

I am new to SQL, and I have been wondering if there is an efficient way to get the number of data that match a condition AND the data both in one SQL command.

Specifically, what I want to achieve is:

1. Check if any records exist in the table that satisfy a user-entered condition
2. If yes, show the data. Otherwise, show "No data found".

It is as simple as this, but with my current SQL knowledge, I can only think of one way to achieve this, and it even requires 2 SQL commands, which I am not really happy about. What I am thinking about is:

```
/*First, count the number of data satisfying the condition.
  If this returns 0, show "No data found" */
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE Condition = "XXX"

/*If the first SQL command returns 1 or greater, retrieve all data 
  and show them */
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Condition = "XXX"
```

However, these two SQL commands are almost the same, and the only difference is that there is COUNT() for the first one, and this is accessing the table twice.
Can this be simplified any further so I can achieve what I want to achieve with possibly one SQL command? Or is there any other way to achieve this more efficiently? Thank you.

Edit: 
Thank you everyone. For your information, I am writing a C# program that accesses the database. I have already used COUNT(*) somewhere, and I was able to retrieve the data count by:

```
string str = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE condition = 'XXX'";
com = new OleDbCommand(str, connection); 
int count = (int)com.ExecuteScalar();
return count;
```

but if one SQL command returns both the count and the data, how could I retrieve the data into one variable?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: This might be necessary, when using pagination.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am using SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the count into the same query which selects all columns given a certain condition, then you can consider using `COUNT()` as an analytic function applied to the entire table.

```
SELECT t.*,
    COUNT(*) OVER () cnt
FROM Table t
WHERE Condition = "XXX"
```

## Demo

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(*), * FROM Table WHERE Condition = "XXX"

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your SQL from a client using a cursor class, the cursor may provide a `rowcount` attribute that identifies the number of rows affected.  If so, then you can simply run `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Condition = 'XXX';` and get the number or rows selected from the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see why you would need `COUNT(*)` at all, but maybe there is more to the requirements that have not been supplied?

If the `SELECT *` result set is empty, then there were no records, and you can display a message to that effect. If the result set isn't empty, then you can process and display the data.